# How to return number of text field in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have 2 text field. When enter number 500 at first field, second field must be enter number more than first field. Results now, either I enter more or less numbers than first field, second field will alert.

I just started writing Javascript Languages. I hope to have some advice for me.

first function

```
let fixNum = () => {
  return v => /^[0-9]+$/.test(v) || `Must be number only`;
};
```

second funtion

```
let num = property => {
  var keep1 = fixNum().value;

  if (property < keep1) {
    return `Number must be morethan Fix Number field`;
  } else {
    return true;
  }
};
```

And I call function in text field (Vuetify)

```
<v-text-field
 v-model="editedItem.fixNumber"
 label="Fix Number"
 outlined
 dense
 required
 :rules="[required('Fix Number'), fixNum()]"
></v-text-field>
```

```
<v-text-field
 v-model="editedItem.number"
 label="Number"
 outlined
 dense
 required
 :rules="[
 required('Number'),
 num(editedItem.number)
 ]"
></v-text-field>
```

Result when enter number less than first field

[image: Result when enter number less than first field]

Result when enter number more than first field

[image: Result when enter number more than first field]

Comment: Where do you have the onChange listener for the first textfield

Comment: Where does the variable `v` come from?

Comment: `fixNum()` doesn't return an object, it returns `true` or `false`. What do you expect `fixNum().value` to be?

Comment: @Asutosh I think the first field is not use onChange.

Comment: @Barmar The variable v is for checking the text entered by the user. If text is not match with regex , it warns user is Must be number only.

And I've tried to return the numbers I received, but it returns number under the field.